# What do the round brackets mean on my unit's offense value in Alpha Centauri?

Tags: alpha-centauri, alien-crossfire

I'm about to build an Impact Skimship at one of my bases. Its values are listed as "(4)-2-4".  Why is the offense value in round brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Round brackets denote **Heavy Artillery** ability.

From [AC Wiki](https://alphacentauri2.info/wiki/Unit#Abilities):

| Name | Designation (with example) | Cost | Prerequisite | Restrictions | Effect | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Heavy Artillery](https://alphacentauri2.info/wiki/Heavy_Artillery) | Adds round brackets around offense number. (8)-?-2*2 | Armor rating + chassis rating. | Polymorphic Software | Only allowed¹ for combat land units. | Allows the unit to engage in #artillery bombardment. Prevents the unit from attacking conventionally. | The unit still defends on its armor rating which is usually low. |

You may also be interested to check the linked page as it describes other abilities like "<4>"-alike defense rating, "2~"-alike attack rating, "2*2"-alike move rating, and more. If you are an avid player in SMAC/SMAX, the entire site is worth reading.

¹) the article says that this ability is "Only allowed for combat land units", which means it can only be *added* to land units. Naval combat units have the intrinsic ability to conduct bombardment and therefore their attack rating always indicates to show this ability, e.g. (4)-2-4 for Skimship.

Comment: That documentation specifically says "Only allowed for combat land units.".  This is a sea unit.

Comment: Probably ought to be mentioned in that Heavy Artillery documentation then as the round brackets still appear for the naval units.